# Почему для хранения времени ипользуют long int, а не unsigned long int?

Tags: время, типы-данных

Если не ошибаюсь, проблема 2038 года касается только тех программ, в которых для работы с временем использовался 32-битный `long int`. Но почему не использовали `unsigned long int`? Ведь при работе с беззнаковым типом это была бы проблема 2106 года.

На Википедии есть соответствующая гифка для знакового типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы думаете найти тут ответ или что-то конкретное?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, хочу понять причину.

Comment: это о каком языке?

Comment: С я так предполагаю.

Comment: @Эникейщик, о Си (и Unix), о чем же еще...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `time()` была введена в Unix в 70-х годах. В то время был только тип `signed long`, тип `unsigned long` был введен в С Керниганом и Ритчи в 1978 г.

Comment: Согласен что не было. Но даже если б было то как пользоваться такими данными.

Comment: Небольшая неточность которая сегодня не важна In 1978, Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie published the first edition of The C Programming Language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language). The second edition of the book ... unsigned int data type. И появилось в 1988 году

Answer (score 2):

Если к разрядности нет вопросов, то хранение в знаковом long int нужно поскольку существуют и даты до 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC. Которые тоже нужно хранить. А в беззнаковых величинах как представить грубо говоря 1960-01-01 00:00:01 UTC. Просто думаю создателям важнее было отрицательные даты нежели дата после 2038 года.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Если в течение часа не будет других ответов, поставлю галочку.